# Model being passed in as null

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework-6

When trying to add a new item to the database (using EF 6.1.3 and MVC 5) my model is always being passed in as null. Here's the model:

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Web;

namespace AccessorizeForLess.ViewModels
{
    public class AddNewProductViewModel
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [DataType(DataType.MultilineText)]
        public string Description { get; set; }

        public decimal Price { get; set; }

        public string AltText { get; set; }

        public int Quantity { get; set; }

        public string ImagePath { get; set; }

        public HttpPostedFileBase Image { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Here's the create method in the controller (I know it's convuluted but I'll work on that )

```
    [HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<ActionResult> Create([Bind(Include="ProductImageId,ProductName,ProductPrice,Quantity,ProductDescription")] AddNewProductViewModel model)
{
    ProductImageViewModel image = new ProductImageViewModel() { ImagePath = "/Content/ProductImages/" + model.Image.FileName, AltText = model.AltText };
    ProductImage newImage = new ProductImage() { ImagePath = image.ImagePath, AltText = image.AltText };
    entities.ProductImages.Add(newImage);
    await entities.SaveChangesAsync();
    int ImageId = newImage.ProductImageId;

    Product product = new Product()
    {
        ProductImageId = ImageId,
        ProductName = model.Name,
        ProductDescription = model.Description,
        ProductPrice = model.Price,
        Quantity = model.Quantity
    };

    string file = model.Image.FileName;
    string path = @"/Content/ProductImages/";

    model.Image.SaveAs(path + file);

    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        entities.Products.Add(product);
        await entities.SaveChangesAsync();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }

    ViewBag.ProductImageId = new SelectList(entities.ProductImages, "ProductImageId", "ImagePath", product.ProductImageId);
    return View("Index");
}
```

And the view:

```
 @model AccessorizeForLess.ViewModels.AddNewProductViewModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Add New Product";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}
@using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "Products", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>Product</h4>
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ImagePath, "Image", new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.ImagePath, new { @type = "file" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ImagePath)
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.AltText, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.AltText)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.AltText)
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name)
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Price, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" ,@width = "25px"})
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Price)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Price)
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Quantity, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Quantity)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Quantity)
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Description, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Description, new { @cols = "25", @rows = "55" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Description)
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT**
@Stephen when I tried to run it again to answer your question I get this

[image]

And have no idea what this is, have you seen anything like this before?

**EDIT**

The error is

Description: An error occurred during the compilation of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific error details and modify your source code appropriately.

> Compiler Error Message: CS1520: Method must have a return type
>
> Source Error:
>
> Line 641:            #line default Line 642:            #line hidden
>   Line 643:BeginContext("~/Views/Products/Create.cshtml", 2361, 9,
>   true); Line 644: Line 645:WriteLiteral("\r\n\r\n");
>
> Source File: c:\Users\Richard\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files\vs\014a60c5\fc8be8b2\App_Web_create.cshtml.c6727781.vcyi-_hh.0.cs
>   Line: 643

**EDIT**

I have this for uploading the image:

```
string file = model.Image.FileName;
string path = Server.MapPath(@"~/Content/ProductImages");
 model.Image.SaveAs(path + "/" + file);
```

I've stepped through it and all the variables are right, it adds the data to the database but doesn't save the image and I cannot for the life of me figure out why?

Comment: Are you saving the model is `null` or just its properties? Note also you need the `enctype = "multipart/form-data"` in your form tag for the file input to be posted back

Comment: @StephenMuecke check my edit and see what you think. Never seen anything like it before

Comment: Bit hard to read the image - can your delete it and just include the relevant error message in the question. But when does that error occur? Is it when you hit the line `return View("Index");`? - which does not actually make sense anyway since it should be `return View(model);`

Comment: @StephenMuecke I edeted the post with the error message

Comment: Bit hard to help - still not sure what your issue is? Is the model `null` when you hit the `Create()` method? And when does that error occur? (put a break point on the first line and step through the code to identify where its occurring)

Comment: I dont know if it's null, I get that error when I try to load the view

Comment: In that case you need to show you GET method

Comment: @StephenMuecke got it working (at least loading) the null reference is happening here **ImagePath = image.ImagePath** (the full code is in the original post)

Comment: How can I populate the model from <input type="file/>?

Comment: Do you mean when you post back? The code you have shown is a bit confusing, but your model should have a property (say) `public HttpPostedFileBase Image { get; set; }` and in the view `@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Image, new { @type = "file" })` and add `enctype = "multipart/form-data"` to your form tag. Then when you POST, property `Image` will contain the file.

Comment: @StephenMuecke I made the changes suggested, but when I click Create all the properties of the model are empty

Comment: Based on your edit, your property for `HttpPostedFileBase` is named `Image` yet your file input is trying to bind to property `ImagePath` (which is typeof `string`) - change you view to `@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Image, new { @type = "file" })`

Comment: @StephenMuecke I made all your suggested changes, and still all the properties come back null when I click the Create button

Comment: Give me 30 minutes and I'll test out your code to see where the error might be.

Comment: @StephenMuecke one more thing (it's adding to the database like it's supposed to so thanks a lot!) but for some reason it's not uploading the image when ** model.Image.SaveAs(path);** gets called

Comment: You have a problem with `string path = @"/Content/ProductImages/";` - your need to use `Server.MapPath()` to correctly specify a path relative to your app. It would need to be something like `string path = Server.MapPath("~/Content/ProductImages");` assuming you have a folder in you app named "Content" with a sub-folder named "ProductImages"

Comment: @StephenMuecke can you check my edit for me, this is causing me to want to pull my hair out :)

Comment: Can't see anything obviously wrong. Can you check what `string fullPath = path + "/" + file;` is returning.

Comment: This is what it gives me: c:\users\richard\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\AccessorizeForLess\AccessorizeForLess\Content\ProductImages\5171_1MainImage(White37-163)-2_1.jpg

Comment: It could possible be a security issue. Try temporarily using `string path = Server.MapPath("~/App_Data");` (ensure you do have an `AppData` folder

Answer (score 0):

Replace:

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Create([Bind(Include="ProductImageId,ProductName,ProductPrice,Quantity,ProductDescription")] AddNewProductViewModel model)
```

with:

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Create([Bind(Include = "ImagePath,AltText,Name,Price,Quantity,Description")] AddNewProductViewModel model)
```